# Create a cd\DVD drive in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to emulate a cdrom or dvd drive using vb.net (2015).
Today I'm using Subst.exe but it does not present itself as a CDrom or DVD drive type - and in some situations it does not work properly.

Any help will be appreciated
Gil

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Can you describe the not working properly piece of it?  I wonder if there's a way we could help with what you have been trying.  Could you post the current code?  What operating system are you using?  [this has potential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/connect-virtualdisk?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Hi, No code for that yet. I'm looking for the starting point. for some reason I can even find a clue

Comment: Which operating system are you on?  [This DiscUtils project may have what you need](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=discutils), and also,  [Here's some more examples](https://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/mounting-iso-files-and-virtual-drives-in-visual-basic.html)